# Gradle build in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I updated my Android Studio to version 3.0.1, and then Gradle to 4.2 and Android plugin tools to 3.0.1. After that whenever I create a new project it gives me the Gradle build problem. 
This is my module build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nasser.studio.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
   compile  fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3'
}
```

Also I unchecked the work offline for gradle.

[image]

I also checked AS settings which displays some errors:

[image]

**Update 1:**
When I change the compile SDK to version 25 like this, the Gradle build is completed correctly.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nasser.studio.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

But changing to latest versions (26 or 27), it gives me the same error. I also should mention that during Gradle build process for these versions, it's downloading files from Maven repositories which doesn't happen in version 25 ( I'm using a proxy connection).

[image]

Moreover, the search box of AS for support library gives me this version which is not the latest version (27.0.2).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use stable **`v7:27.0.2`** instead off **`v7:27.0.3`**.

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"
```

**FYI**

If you are using **Android Studio 3.0 or above make sure**, your **`build.gradle`** **(PROJECT level)** file looks like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: Thanks, Intellij but it doesn't work again. Also when I change to v7:27.0.2, Android Studio tells me to a new version is available.

Comment: @nassertahani Its a warning. Tell me same error coming or not?

Comment: The error is same except it's been changed to v7:27.0.2 in error dialog.

Comment: @yes. I tested both of 'google()' and 'maven { } ' for maven repositories.

Comment: Thanks, IntelliJ. If you mean adding both of 'google()' and 'maven{ }' to the build.gradle file, I did it with no success.

Comment: @nassertahani using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this version of Android Plugin.

Comment: @nassertahani Very strange case. I guess Sloppy mistake coming.

Comment: Yeah, it seems and there is no solution by now.

Comment: @nassertahani Fixed yet?

Comment: IntelliJ, Not yet with the latest version. Check the update, please.

Comment: @nassertahani Looks like SDK issue

Comment: Download new sdk.

Comment: Are you sure it's sth about SDK? because when I want to use 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0' it gives me the same error which unable to resolve dependency for that too. @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @nassertahani Solved ??

Comment: Yes, it was some proxy problem for connecting to Google maven repositories. Also, your tip about changing the v7:27.0.2 was helpful and critical.

Comment: @nassertahani move ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your project level build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this on your Project level `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `27.0.2`, `27.0.3` not relesed yet

Answer (score 0):

first, check with your gradle-wrapper.properties which should be having this

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

and in project-level build.gradle

```
build script {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

also you need to change according this 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations

and see the topic **Migrate dependency configurations for local modules**
you will get better idea what things need to change in dependencies.